# Save BooleanArray in LibgGDX Preferences

Tags: java, android, arrays, libgdx, sharedpreferences

I have a long `BooleanArray` in my LibgGDX game, to save it in my `Preferences` i do this:

```
static Preferences prefs;

public static void putMyArray (BooleanArray booleanArray, String string){
    for(int i=0; i < booleanArray.size;i++){
        prefs.putBoolean( string+i, booleanArray.get(i));
    }
}
```

This method can work for small, array but for my case the size is 100+.

please help, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it super compact, you can use the Kryo library to convert it to binary. Then you could save it as a local file or convert it to a String Preference if you use a ByteArrayOutputStream.

There is already a [library with serializers for LibGDX](https://github.com/CypherCove/gdx-cclibs/tree/master/gdxtokryo) data classes in Kryo.

Add the library to your core project in build.gradle:

```
compile "com.cyphercove.gdx:gdxtokryo:1.1.1"
```

Saving to file:

```
kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setRegistrationRequired(true);
GdxToKryo.registerGroup(kryo, 0);
Output output = new Output(Gdx.files.local("mySave.bin").write(false));
kryo.writeObject(output, myBooleanArray);
output.close();
```

Reading the data:

```
kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setRegistrationRequired(true);
GdxToKryo.registerGroup(kryo, 0);
Input input = new Input(Gdx.files.local("mySave.bin").read());
BooleanArray myBooleanArray = kryo.readObject(input, BooleanArray.class);
input.close();
```

Comment: thank you and upvoted @Tenfour04 , is there any other way with no libraries

Comment: Write to a ByteArrayOutputStream. Output that to a String with a specific encoding so you can save it as a String preference, or write it directly to a local file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use BitSet of java.(its core java library) [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

There are 2 reasons for BitSet.

- BitSet have toLongArray() method.(and vice versa valueOf(long[] longs) )

You can convert bits to long type and store as long.

- Java's boolean array is not that good to use.

[Hidden evils of Java’s boolean array (boolean[])](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/hidden-evils-of-javas-byte-array-byte)

```
 BitSet bits = new BitSet(180);//lets say u have 180 bools

bits.set(0); // set the 0th bit.means we changed 0th bit to true
bits.set(7); // set the 7th bit
bits.set(8); // set the 8th bit
...
//save
long[] allbits=bits.toLongArray(); //u need 3 long type members to store 180 bools since long is 64 bit
arrsize=allbits.length;
prefs.putInteger("longarraysize",arrsize);
    for(int i=0 ; i < arrsize ; i++){
    prefs.putLong( string+i, allbits[i]); // long values stored in prefs
}


//load
arrsize=getInteger("longarraysize",0);
long[arrsize] allbits;
for(int i=0 ; i < arrsize ; i++){
allbits[i]=getLong(string+i,0); //we get all long values we stored
}
Bitset bits=BitSet.valueOf(allbits);//Converted long array to bits again.


if(bits.get(15))
{
//do something if 15th bit is true
}
```

Comment: I added a small example.